# Solution to RESTFul authentication over HTTPS

Tags: security, restful-authentication

therez really a lot of discussion on the web for authentication is REST Architecture, so i think its a high time we place the solution at one place.A solution that sound somewhat ok:

(Security professionals out there, plz comment)

1. The user log in using his username and password
2. On the server, username and password is validated
3. if credentials are valid, we get a unique id by mixing a timestamp with the userid. we use a table for mapping uniqueId->userid and we make an entry for the unique id we just generated and the userid
4. Also, we set an HTTP header say id containing the unique id and the userid somewhat with string concatenation  like this `<uniqueId>#<userid>.`
5. On every request the client must supply this info,
6. if a request from the client require us to identify who the client is so that we can check his permissions, then we do this:

get http header  #,

if not contain invalid user

if contain check in database if mapping uniqueId->userid exist

if yes we have identified the user else invalid user

**The whole of this scheme is on HTTPS**

Comment: I would consider using something that exists like [OpenID](http://openid.net/) instead of inventing something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need such a complex solution if you are over HTTPS. You could even ask the client to transmit the username and password with every request. As long as the client is not compromised, there's no problem. And if it is compromised, the whole solution falls apart anyway.

In general, I think most dev are interested in a solution over HTTP, not HTTPS. But for that there are already proven solutions like OpenID or OAuth.